# python, trouble installing with pip

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, pip

I am trying to instal the python version of openGL on my mac. When I use the command given by the [site](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) `pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate` I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking PyOpenGL
  Downloading PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3.tar.gz (939kB): 939kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PyOpenGL
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: -c --help-commands

   or: -c cmd --help



error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2m/chhqrrdn6698hyx3mt1gtcg00000gp/T/pip-build-lego90511/PyOpenGL
Storing complete log in /Users/lego90511/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

After some searching, most people tend to be missing some utility or another, but it is never the same thing. So what am I missing?

Comment: Just to cover the bases, are you using the most recent ``pip`` and ``setuptools``?

Comment: I'm not so sure, I am working with python 2.7.5 and what ever pip came with that. How/should I grade pip, and setuptools? Would it be better to use easy_install?

Comment: ``pip install pip setuptools --upgrade`` (perhaps with ``sudo``). You can check the versions of installed packages with ``pip list``. AFAIK ``pip`` is the preferred package manager now.

Comment: I tried to do the upgrade, but I got the same problem "error: invalid command 'egg_info'"

Comment: Well, at least you know now that your problem is not OpenGL-related :) So, what ``pip`` and ``setuptools`` versions do you have?

Comment: pip 1.3.1, setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846

Comment: Your ``setuptools`` are *really* old... I think it's even before the merger with ``distutils``. They claim to support updates from 0.6, but apparently it doesn't always work. Try to [update them manually](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.5#id123).

Comment: had to run pip install --upgrade setuptools with sudo, but now I'm at setuptools .6c11, is that better? I'm guessing since the list goes to 1.1.5, no.

Comment: ok manually updated setuptools, which came with easy_install, so I tried to use that to install PyopenGL. It ran through the process, I think. The .egg files are there, but I can't find the actual libraries.